# What does the gray gap in the NV election site bar means?

Tags: united-states, election, nevada

The official Nevada (Clark county) site shows the ballot count results and has a bar with Red and Blue percents, as well as a gray gao between them. What does this gray bar means? Is it the remaining uncounted ballots?bor something else?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everyone who is not DEM or GOP, including a choice of “none of these”. Look for example at some of the State Assembly where there is no gray, and click on “show details.” Those with no gray have only two candidates and no one voted for “none of these” (or not enough to make it visible). (Note: Some have only a Republican and an IAP, so there is red and green and no gray.)